# Increase maxTokensPerLine in Atom.IO

Tags: atom-editor

How can I increase maxTokensPerLine in my own Atom.IO environment?

I've got some long lines causing syntax to not be recognized properly, for example not highlighted correctly and brackets not taken note of etc.

But this seems to be a current source containing it. It seems to be taken as a parameter which suggests it could be configurable?
[grammar-registry.coffee](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/62c1bad39c5347010c81ee8baf6b607caaa10cb6/src/grammar-registry.coffee)

I found
`this.maxTokensPerLine = (_ref1 = options.maxTokensPerLine) != null ? _ref1 : Infinity;`
on line 22 of `/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/first-mate/lib/grammar-registry.js`
maxTokensPerLine also appears in
`/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/first-mate/lib/grammar.js`

I tried adding `maxTokensPerLine: 1000` in `config.cson` under *, core and editor, but it had no effect.

(old) maxTokensPerLine
[syntax.coffee](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/e3641286e71447a79666682edf04570b156b67cc/src/syntax.coffee#L30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package [`grammar-token-limit`](https://github.com/postcasio/atom-grammar-token-limit), which will handle changing it for you. All you need to do is specify which value you want in the package settings.

I guess if you want to do it yourself, this package would be the place to start looking.

Comment: For me grammar-token-limit doesn't even help after about 250 characters, at least in JavaScript :/

Comment: That sounds like a different problem that often gets confused with this one. `maxTokensPerLine` is for how many matches it will make, but the editor will still give up after a line of certain length. For this, add `limitLinelength = false` to something. It may work in the config file, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah ok. Do you have any idea where `limitLinelength = false` should go?

Comment: Actually, do you mean 250 highlighted characters? If so, the only solution is to increase the token limit using that package, or break it over several lines. And it seems `limitLineLength` can only be set in the language package itself.